# VS Code c++ debugger jumps over class functions instead of stepping into

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, c++17, vscode-debugger

I have a Class for an ADT which is organized into a .h header file and .cpp implementation file.

I'm attempting to test the class and I need the debugger to step into one of the class functions inside the .cpp implementation file. However, whenever I press step into the debugger just jumps over the function. I've tried to look for solutions but only find them from Visual Studio. Keep in mind that I am using Visual Studio Code! turning off "just my code" is not an option for me.

How can I make the debugger step into the functions inside my .h/.cpp files for my class? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know why you can't step into, but you can always put a breakpoint in your function and then run.

Comment: Is debugging information enabled for your cpp files?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm not sure I follow  you. Can you explain what you mean by debugging information?

Comment: @MatG I tried that but the debugger still skips the function call

Comment: When you build your code you have to enable embedding debugging information in each file or you can't debug it

Comment: @AlanBirtles I did not realize I skipped the -g on the ADT file. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Question has been resolved in the comments. Since I have a lengthy makeFile, I forgot to add the debugging option when compiling my ADT files.

Comment: the perils of hand crafted make files, I'd recommend investigating cmake or meson. The cmake plugin for vscode makes vscode much easier to use